Delphi 12.1 Post installation configuration
I've gotten Delphi 12.0 to work on Android, IOS, and Linux. I was quite happy with it. I finished the trial, bought a license, and installed 12.1, only to find out that all my settings were "lost"
Starting with Version Control:

SDK Manager (all tabs):

I can still see the Build profiles for Mac and Linux in my Documents folder however, they are not accessible from Delphi:

How do I enable the "old" settings, can they be recovered at all and what are the proper settings for the Android SDK?
When I like to connect to my Mac I get:
Connection refused. Platform Assistant Server version mismatch - expecting version '14.1.13.8'.

A new Platform Assistant Server installer package has been copied to directory '/Users/XXXX/PAServer/scratch-dir/XXX-MacBookAir/' on host machine '192.168.1.46'. Please
reinstall and restart the Platform Assistant Server to resolve this problem.

What's that about?

I can't answer the first part, but for the second part (Platform Assistant Server), a new version has been copied to your MAC in directory /Users/XXXX/PAServer/scratch-dir/XXX-MacBookAir/ that you need to install on your MAC.

When you installed the update, did it not ask you to preserve your existing settings before it removed 12.0?

@RemyLebeau, can't remember but if it did I am sure I would have selected it

The mean part is that the question is not "do you want to preserve the settings", but "do you want to remove the settings". Although the default answer is "No", you would not be the first one wrongly answering "Yes".

What are the proper settings for Android as Delphi doesn't compile with the default settings

Thanks to a post in a forum I found:
https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/10436-delphi-120-athens-is-not-correctly-installing-the-android-sdk/
Go to:
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-23.0.51961.7529\cmdline-tools\11.0\bin
(I guess over time "AndroidSDK-2525-23.0.51961.7529" will change)
Find a file named sdkmanager.bat.
Open a cmd prompt in this folder and enter these commands:
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-33"
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-34"

I did 34 as that's the latest one I see in Android SDK Manager installed on my PC.
----- update -----
I had a response from Embarcadero support, looks like the issue is that I did not execute the installer and related processes using "Run as Administrator". I guess I will do that the next time and hope that this avoids any issues.
Here is the support response:

Thank you for contacting Embarcadero support.
Make sure that you are using the latest Rad Studio 12 Update 1 (12.1),
which has just been released. If you need the media, navigate to the
link below:
https://my.embarcadero.com
First login, then click on the cloud icon with down arrow. Then scroll
down and click on the following:
RAD Studio, Delphi, C++Builder 12.1 Web Install
After downloading, make sure to extract the contents of the zip to
your hard drive. After the extraction completes, navigate into the
extracted folder, right-click on the setup/install executable and
choose, 'Run as Administrator'.
If you have already installed the 12.1 media (with 'Run as
Administrator'), then proceed with the instructions below:
Start Rad Studio 12.1 by right-clicking on the shortcut and choose,
'Run as Administrator', and when the product opens, go to Tools |
Options | Deployment | SDK Manager | select the Android configurations
and click Delete, then click Save.
Next, go to Tools | Manage Platforms...| Additional Options and select
the following features and click Apply:
'Android SDK 25.2.5 - NDK r21' 'Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK 11 (HotSpot)
JVM'
If these features are already installed, select the options and
uninstall. Then shutdown and restart Rad Studio by right-clicking on
the shortcut and choose, 'Run as Administrator', and when the product
opens, select the above features and Apply.
Once the install is complete, restart the product using 'Run as
Administrator' and retest running a Delphi multi-device project
targeting Android.
Let me know how it goes,
Christopher Moeller

I hope it helps someone.
